# Instantiate a new script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I know this is easy and I can do it if it's a GameObject, but how do I instantiate a new script?

```
Instantiate(FleeScript);
```

I get errors for that.

Comment: What are the errors? Could you please give more information?

Comment: Expression denotes a 'type' where a veraible value or method group was expeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember: a script must be in a GameObject.

So, to get an instance of a new script you either add it to a GameObject:

```
GameObject myGameObject = ...
FleeScript fleeScript = myGameObject.AddComponent<FleeScript>();
// do something with fleeScript
```

or you have a prefab that already contains that script and instantiate that prefab:

```
public class MyOtherScript
{
    public FleeScript prefabWithFleeScript; // Linked from the Editor

    void Awake()
    {
        FleeScript fleeScript= Instantiate(prefabWithFleeScript);
        // do something with fleeScript
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah ended up using AddComponent. I would have been fine with setting the Component to enabled/disabled but the guy I'm working with did something funky to the code and it still behaved even though his script was turned off.

Comment: Yeah, the enabled flag will still call Awake, even if it's false. A lot of people forget that, myself included ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destroying and instantiating new script, I enable and disable them using GetComponent.enabled = true/false.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void AttachScript(GameObject obj, string scriptClassName)
{
    if (obj != null)
        obj.AddComponent(scriptClassName);
}

public static void AttachScript(string gameObjectName, string scriptClassName)
{
    var obj = GameObject.Find(gameObjectName);
    if (obj != null)
        obj.AddComponent(scriptClassName);
}
```

Note:

1. the argument "scriptClassName" is the class name, not "scriptClassName.cs"
2. You should make sure the script class file exists in the project folder or subfolders